# iOS - double UITabBarControllerDelegate cancels behavior

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Swift application with 4 bottom tabs. In the home tab I have a video running. In the 4th tab I have a favorites list.

When the user changes tabs, if he's on the home screen, the video should stop. Also, when the user taps on the 4th tab, the favorites list should update so that the user can see the recent additions.

I have the following on the home tab view controller:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    print("TAB CHANGED")
    if let jwp = jwPlayer {
        jwp.stop()
    }
}
```

and this on the favorites tab view controller:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
    
    if tabBarIndex == 3 {
        let userId = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "userId")
        favoritesVC.updateData(with: userId)
    }
}
```

Both conform to UITabBarControllerDelegate. Both include:

```
self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
```

When I launch the app, the video starts playing, I tap on any tab and the video stops. No matter which tab I tap on I see the message "TAB CHANGED". But as soon as I tap on the favorites tab and I move to another, I stop seeing the "TAB CHANGED" message. If I then move to the home screen and play the video and then move to a different tab, the video no longer stops.

The didSelect on the 4th tab is cancelling the didSelect on the 1st tab.

How can I get both of them to work? I have placed them on both view controllers because on the first one I need to reference the video and on the 2nd one I need to reference the list view controller (the 4th view controller actually has two top tabs which switch between a favorites vc and a downloads vc).

**UPDATE:**

I moved the delegate to the TabBarController subclass. I added the following:

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex

    let hvc = HomeViewController()
    if tabBarIndex != 0 {
        hvc.stopPlayer()
    }
}
```

I added

```
delegate = self
```

and

```
class TabBarViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
```

In the HomeViewController I added this:

```
func stopPlayer() {
    print("TAB CHANGED")
    if let jwp = jwPlayer {
        jwp.stop()
    }
}
```

however when I change tabs, jwPlayer is always nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are handling the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` calbacks in multiple places and for that to happen, you are also changing following multiple times -

```
self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
```

Here's what you should do -

1. Handle `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in one place.
2. Dispatch the necessary work calls from there to relevant screens.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {

   if tabBarIndex == 0 {
       homeVC.startPlayer()
   }
   else {
       homeVC.stopPlayer()
       
       if tabBarIndex == 3 {
           let userId = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "userId")
           favoritesVC.updateData(with: userId)
       }
    }
}
```

This can be handled anywhere, inside your TabBarController subclass if you have one, or any other object that is guaranteed to exist for the application lifetime.

Comment: Can you please check the update I added? I tried what you suggested but it's not working.

Comment: `let hvc = HomeViewController()` is a brand new instance of that screen, NOT the one that you are seeing on the screen. You need to call the method on existing instance, that's currently visible on the screen.

Comment: How can I reference the existing instance?

Comment: Maybe - `tabBarController.viewControllers.first as? HomeViewController` OR `(tabBarController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController)?.viewControllers.first as? HomeViewController`

Comment: Thanks, I ended making the viewControllers properties in the TabBarViewController and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

TabBarController’s delegate does not have to be either of the view controllers. It could be some other object (not even a view controller) that could hold weak references to both view controllers, for example, or post a notification etc